# Adding indexes in array

Tags: actionscript-3

I am adding two matrices (or possibly many) in ActionScript 3.0.

Now my problem is how can I add indexes in array that is something like this?

```
array1[1,2,3,4] + array2[2,4,5,6] = answer[3,6,8,10]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function adds up all the arrays that are passed to it:

```
function sumOfArrays(...args):Array
{
    var sum:Array = [];
    var arrays:Array = [];
    var longestArrayLength:uint = 0;

    for (var i:int = 0, n:int = args.length; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (args[i] is Array)
        {
            arrays.push(args[i]);
            longestArrayLength = args[i].length > longestArrayLength ? args[i].length : longestArrayLength;
        }
    }

    for (var j:int = 0; j < longestArrayLength; j++)
    {
        sum[j] = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum[j] += isNaN(arrays[i][j]) ? 0 : arrays[i][j];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

It can be used like this:
`var sum:Array = sumOfArrays(array1, array2);`

Comment: Wow...really works like charm..i have nothing to say.. this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Arrays only allows access via one index. You'd have to write a method on your own for this. But be aware of the fact, that null would be referenced on answer at, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5 and so on.

Comment: You know the algorithm for that method you mean? I saw one tutorial in php using array_map and array_sum but I think there is no methods like that in as3 so i have to create one.

Comment: No, it would be basically 4 arrays, two source array and two containing the indices. The rest would be constructed by the method via for-loop.